# GMS Huawei devices and google services provider issue

Tags: android

I'm facing an issue with Huawei devices I'm using a firbace service and the app is not running on the  Huawei GMS devices not supporting to run the app, the device supports google play and I can download the app from google play but I get error for fairbace service cannot login.

If there any idea why the Huawei GMS devices get effected? And how can I fix this issue.

Thank you

i have stooped supporting the HMS devices and it should not effects the GMS devices becase it's supported by google service as i can use the google play but it's not